# Splitting out timestamp/key/value pairs from bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have this file full of data; the time stamps is basically the beginning of the line. I need to break down the file and print each line individually. How can I accomplish this using only bash and (if needed) standard UNIX tools (sed, awk, etc)?

The time stamp field goes from  08:30:00:324810:  onward .. example    17:30:00:324810: . The number of field following the time stamp varies; so there could be 1 to x number of fields .  So I need to  find the time stamp format and then insert a page break.

```
08:30:00:324810: usg_07Y  BidYield=1.99788141 Bid=99.20312500 08:30:00:325271: usg_07Y
AskYield=1.98578274 Ask=99.28125000 08:30:00:325535: usg_10Y  Ask=0.00000000 08:30:01:324881: 
usg_07Y  BidYield=2.02938740 AskYield=1.97127853 Bid=99.00000000 Ask=99.37500000 08:30:01:377021:
usg_05Y  Bid=0.00000000 Ask=0.00000000
```

Thanking u in advance
Matt

Comment: Does it have to be sed/awk?  Can it be something else like perl/ruby/python for example?

Comment: "How do I use X to do Y?" rather than "How do I do Y?" is a great way to get answers no better than those you could come up with yourself. Maybe X isn't the right tool to use for Y. If you're asking for expert advice, why put restrictions on it?

Comment: ...to be more clear -- you could do this in native bash with no dependency on *any* external tool, _including_ `sed` or `awk`... but for some reason you appear not to want that answer.

Comment: Since you accepted an answer that requires neither `sed` or `awk`, I'm presuming those weren't **really** part of your question, and that editing the stated requirement out would be in line with intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly trivial. Read the file into an `array`, find the `timestamp`, output a `newline` before it:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f                          # inhibit globbing (filename expansion)
declare -i cnt=0                # simple counter

a=( $(<"$1") )                  # read file into array
for i in "${a[@]}"; do          # for each word in file
    if [ "$cnt" -gt 0 ]; then   # test counter > 0
        # if last char ':', then output newline before word
        [ ${i:(-1):1} = ':' ] && printf "\n%s" "${i}" || printf " %s" "$i"
    else
        printf "%s" "$i"        # if first word, just print.
    fi
    ((cnt++))
done
printf "\n"
```

**Use/output:**

```
$ bash parsedtstamp.sh filename.txt
08:30:00:324810: usg_07Y BidYield=1.99788141 Bid=99.20312500
08:30:00:325271: usg_07Y AskYield=1.98578274 Ask=99.28125000
08:30:00:325535: usg_10Y Ask=0.00000000
08:30:01:324881: usg_07Y BidYield=2.02938740 AskYield=1.97127853 Bid=99.00000000 Ask=99.37500000
08:30:01:377021: usg_05Y Bid=0.00000000 Ask=0.00000000
```

I added a counter var to only output the newline if not the first word.

---

**Alternate version that avoids temporary array storage (for large files)**

While there is no limit on array size in Bash, if you find yourself parsing million line files, it is probably better to avoid storing all lines in memory. This can be accomplished by simply processing the lines as they are read from the file. It is just a way of doing to same thing without using an array for intermediate storage:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f                              # inhibit globbing (filename expansion)
declare -i cnt=0                    # simple counter

# read each line in file
while read -r line_entries || [ -n "$line_entries" ]; do
    for i in $line_entries; do      # for each word in line (no quotes for word splitting)
        if [ "$cnt" -gt 0 ]; then   # test counter > 0
            # if last char ':', then output newline before word
            if [ ${i:(-1):1} = ':' ]; then
                printf "\n%s" "${i}"
            else
                printf " %s" "$i"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s" "$i"        # if first word, just print.
        fi
        ((cnt++))                   # increment counter
    done
done <"$1"

printf "\n"
```

Comment: Is the lack of quotes when expanding `${a[@]}`, or later when expanding `${i:(-1):1}`, intentional? Other than that particular decision, this answer looks ideal to me (other than violating the `sed` / `awk` requirement).

Comment: Yes and No (like that qualification?). All words were read separately into the array (separated by whitespace), so you can quote or not quote without changing the result here. It would be more properly quoted `:)`

Comment: You might also want to suppress glob expansion when loading the file into array that way.

Comment: Re: whether you can quote or not quote depends. If the file contains a `*`, and it expands to a filename containing a literal `*` surrounded by spaces, then you'd get expansion twice rather than once.

Comment: check back. I'll have a few tweaks based on the master's suggestions `:)`

Comment: ok David - Can u pls explain  ${i:(-1):1} = ':' << how this piece of code work?

Comment: Yes, that is **character indexing**, `${var:start:length}` however to check from the end of the string you must **enclose start in parens** or **leave a space before the number**. So that just means look at the **end** char with a length of `1`. (the last char)

Comment: Almost perfect. Only other change I'd suggest is `set -f` at the start (before the array assignment), to inhibit globbing when the file's contents are split. (That, or doing the assignment a completely different way; ie. `a=(); while read -r -a line_entries; do a+=( "${line_entries[@]}" ); done`)

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, per Charles good catch, I have quoted `"${a[@]}"` to prevent file expansion in case the word in `a` also matched a filename.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thank you for your experienced eye `:)`

Comment: Glad to help. This _is_ a really great answer, tweaks notwithstanding; I'm happy to see more folks grokking bash deeply. :)

Comment: After 15 years of this stuff, I better have learned a little or I should just pack it up and go home...

Comment: ...by the way, if you were writing this for bash only, you could instead of `[ ${i:(-1):1} = ':' ]` write `[[ $i = *: ]]`; personal preference plays in, but arguably a touch easier to read.

Comment: (Also, if I'm being really, _really_ nitpicky, using `a && b || c` as a substitute for `if a; then b; else c; fi` isn't always a great practice -- because if `b` fails, then you can run `c` even in a case where `a` returned true. Completely harmless here, though, since the only cases the first `printf` could fail would cause the second one to fail too).

Comment: (There are also side effects inasmuch as having the `|| c` makes `b` be considered to be "checked", so its failure doesn't cause `set -e` to exit the script early, an `ERR` trap to fire, etc; whereas in the `if` case only `a` is considered checked for purposes of suppressing `set -e`).

Comment: Ahh, you know I thought about that and thought about including and `if` `then` `else`, but from a compactness standpoint didn't. A failure in `b` (it being a `printf` in this case) is something I did NOT consider. Good stuff. Thank you again. Real world calls, gotta run, back in an hour or so...

Comment: Hi David. Sorry for delayed response. I'm grateful for the code and all the details. It works like a charm and I have accomplish what I needed to work. Kudos to you

Answer (score 0):

An awk way

```
awk -vORS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/:$/&&x++)$i="\n"$i}$NF=$NF" "
               END{print "\n"}' file
```

Sets output record sep to nothing.
Loops through fields.
If fields last char is `:` then it add a newline before the field.
Adds space to last field in case it is a date to prevent no space between colon and next field.
Prints a newline at the end.